# Sum of all the numbers in a column for 3 tables?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to use PHP and SQL to echo the sum of columns from 3 separate tables. I'm wondering how I can simplify this as it's very bloated.

Thanks!

```
public function getTotalSum() {
    include("dbconnect.php");
    $query1 = "SELECT SUM(column1) AS 'count' FROM table1";
    $query2 = "SELECT SUM(column2) AS 'count' FROM table2";
    $query3 = "SELECT SUM(column3) AS 'count' FROM table3";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($sqlcon, $query1);
    $result2 = mysqli_query($sqlcon, $query2);
    $result3 = mysqli_query($sqlcon, $query3);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
        while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc() + $result2->fetch_assoc() + $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['count'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify what I mean. I have 3 tables with a column in each of then. I want to get the sum of the 3 columns from the 3 tables.

Comment: Did you try [`join`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one sql query instead of multiple ones. 
Apply the following approach:

```
public function getTotalSum() {
    include("dbconnect.php");
    $query = "SELECT 
                (SELECT SUM(column1) AS 'count' FROM table1)
                + (SELECT SUM(column2) AS 'count' FROM table2)
                + (SELECT SUM(column3) AS 'count' FROM table3) AS count;    
    ";
    $result = mysqli_query($sqlcon, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo $row['count'];
    }
}
```